Error in ezANOVA bootstrapping for repeated measures ANOVA
I am having trouble with the following code. I am trying to bootstrap a repeated measures anova. I keep getting an error that my data contains NA values, although no NA values seem to be there - I tried removing na values, fixing data type etc...
Here is the code:
boot_reg <- function(data, i) {

d2 <- data[i, ]

row.names(d2) <- NULL

d2$condition <- as.factor(d2$condition)

d2$Day <- as.factor(d2$Day)

d2$participant <- as.factor(d2$participant)

d2$value <- as.numeric(d2$value)

d2 <- na.omit(d2)

print((d2))



fit <- ezANOVA(data = d2, dv = .(value), wid = .(participant),

between = .(condition), within = .(Day), type = "III")

print(fit)



f_values <- fit$ANOVA$'F'



return(f_values)

}




bOrigMax <- boot::boot(data = df_long, boot_reg, R = 1000)

The error I get:
Warning: You have removed one or more Ss from the analysis. Refactoring "participant" for ANOVA.
Warning: Data is unbalanced (unequal N per group). Make sure you specified a well-considered value for the type argument to ezANOVA().
Warning: Collapsing data to cell means. IF the requested effects are a subset of the full design, you must use the "within_full" argument, else results may be inaccurate.
Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within, :
One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.
The data (df_long):
participant condition Day value
1 10 experimental Day1 2.416667
2 11 control Day1 2.458333
3 12 experimental Day1 2.700000
4 13 control Day1 2.177273
5 14 experimental Day1 2.333333
6 15 control Day1 2.295455
7 16 experimental Day1 2.482609
8 17 control Day1 1.669565
9 18 experimental Day1 2.341667
10 19 control Day1 2.420833
11 21 control Day1 2.359091
12 22 experimental Day1 2.404167
13 24 experimental Day1 2.058333
14 25 control Day1 2.091304
15 30 experimental Day1 1.891304
16 31 control Day1 2.458824
17 32 experimental Day1 1.943478
18 33 control Day1 1.883333
19 34 experimental Day1 2.226087
20 35 control Day1 2.263636
21 36 experimental Day1 2.791667
22 39 control Day1 2.508333
23 42 experimental Day1 2.104348
24 43 control Day1 2.637500
25 44 experimental Day1 2.400000
26 45 control Day1 2.875000
27 10 experimental Day2 2.495652
28 11 control Day2 2.526087
29 12 experimental Day2 2.687500
30 13 control Day2 1.958333
31 14 experimental Day2 2.500000
32 15 control Day2 2.266667
33 16 experimental Day2 2.587500
34 17 control Day2 1.550000
35 18 experimental Day2 2.437500
36 19 control Day2 2.133333
37 21 control Day2 2.239130
38 22 experimental Day2 2.572727
39 24 experimental Day2 2.438095
40 25 control Day2 2.341667
41 30 experimental Day2 2.087500
42 31 control Day2 2.285000
43 32 experimental Day2 2.309091
44 33 control Day2 2.211111
45 34 experimental Day2 2.409091
46 35 control Day2 2.168421
47 36 experimental Day2 2.990909
48 39 control Day2 2.533333
49 42 experimental Day2 2.020833
50 43 control Day2 2.595833
51 44 experimental Day2 2.658824
52 45 control Day2 2.895833
